# Issues with installing tweepy with Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, tweepy

I'm getting this error while trying to install Tweepy Package for python (i'm working with anconda prompt):

```
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(337): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::pyjwt-1.5.3-py_0'.
CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\Scripts\conda.exe
Running `conda clean --packages` may resolve your problem.
Attempting to roll back.


CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\Scripts\conda.exe
Running `conda clean --packages` may resolve your problem.
```

I followed the suggestion and ran 'conda clean --packages' and then tried to install it again, using `conda install -c conda-forge tweepy`, suffice to say it didn't work and I'm getting the following error :

```
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(337): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::pyjwt-1.5.3-py_0'.
CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\Scripts\conda.exe
Running `conda clean --packages` may resolve your problem.
Attempting to roll back.


CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\Scripts\conda.exe
Running `conda clean --packages` may resolve your problem.
```

Any help here? I'm using python 2.7, Anconda2-5.0.1 and Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same exact error as yours. If you check tweepy's Github https://github.com/tweepy/tweepyyou you will read that the easiest way to install `tweepy` is by using `pip`, so you should follow that way instead.

So in case you haven't installed `pip` using `conda`, then type at the `conda` command prompt

```
conda install pip
```

Then again on the command prompt

`pip install tweepy`

It should work now

Comment: yeah it was rather confusing using pip and when you have a dedicated anaconda-cmd, thanks it worked!